# Should React higher order components (hoc) provide names for props that are contextual?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Since HOCs are suppose to be used as mixins, potentially along with other HOCs, would it preferable to inject prop names that are contextual albeit verbose (eg. prefixed with the name of the HOC)?

I suppose this should be considered a question of what should be best practice.

So for example, which is better for this HOC for injecting window-like behavior:

***short non-contextual naming***

```js
@window
@otherMixin
class BasicView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {close, open} = this.props; //these are provided by @window
  }
}
```

VS ***contextual naming (prefixed)***

```js
@window
@otherMixin
class BasicView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {windowClose, windowOpen} = this.props //these are provided by @window
  }
}
```

OR ***contextual naming (nested)***

```js
@window
@otherMixin
class BasicView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {window} = this.props; //provided by @window
    window.open();
    window.close();

    /*  optionally we can destructure and work with the shorter 
     *  non-contextually named props while still maintaining 
     *  a declaration of their context to disambiguate
     */  
    //const {window: {open, close} } = this.props; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally library designers provide this with react context and a hoc to subscribe to the context object. It might be your case that using context is unnecessary. However, most library designers are limited by "contextual naming (nested)" because that's how context works.

This question is really just a matter of personal opinion, but if you want to follow the pattern of other libraries that's what you should choose.

On a last note, I would strongly recommend against proving a variable named `window` ever for obvious reasons.

Comment: Even without using react context, I do find that the "contextual naming (nested)" pattern to be the better for reasons such as the minimal footprint on the props namespace. Unfortunately not all HOC libraries follow this, prompt my question here